# Writing partial unique_ptr for C++03 compiler which operates on common codebase with newer compilers

Tags: c++, templates, unique-ptr, c++03

I need to write an implementation of `unique_ptr` for C++03 which would only absorb changes made in common codebase under other platforms where C++11 is enabled. Namely, it doesn't need to check anything, everything will be checked by other platforms compilers. But it needs to properly pass and destroy objects.

This is an example of testing code. And [full test online](http://cpp.sh/9alez).

```
template <class T> std2::unique_ptr<T> pass_through(std2::unique_ptr<T> p) { return p; }
...
std2::unique_ptr<A> a1 = std2::make_unique<B>();
std2::unique_ptr<A> a2 = std2::move(pass_through(a1));                             // doesn't work
std2::unique_ptr<A> a2 = (const std2::unique_ptr<A>&)std2::move(pass_through(a1)); // doesn't work
std2::unique_ptr<A> a2 = (const std2::unique_ptr<B>&)std2::move(pass_through(a1)); // works
std2::unique_ptr<B> a2 = std2::move(pass_through(a1));                             // works
```

unique_ptr implementation:

```
class Num { protected: static int i; }; int Num::i = 0;

template<class Data>
class unique_ptr : Num
{
    int _i = i++;
    mutable Data *_data;

public:
    explicit unique_ptr(Data* data = nullptr) 
    { _data = data; std::cout << _i << ": cons" << std::endl; }

    template<class T>
    unique_ptr(unique_ptr<T>& other) :
        _data((Data*)other.release())
    { std::cout << _i << ": copy cons <T>" << std::endl; }

    template<class T>
    unique_ptr(const unique_ptr<T>& other) :
        _data((Data*)other.release())
    { std::cout << _i << ": copy cons const <T>" << std::endl; }

    ~unique_ptr() { std::cout << _i << ": deleting :" << _data << std::endl; delete _data; _data = 0; }

    unique_ptr& operator=(Data* data)
    { reset(data); return *this; }

    template<class T>
    unique_ptr& operator=(unique_ptr<T>& other) {
        std::cout << "assign <T>" << std::endl;
        reset((Data*)other.release());
        return *this;
    }

    template<class T>
    unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr<T>& other) {
        std::cout << "assign const <T>" << std::endl;
        reset((Data*)other.release());
        return *this;
    }

    operator bool() const { return _data != nullptr; }

    Data* release() const
    { Data* res = _data; _data = nullptr; return res; }

    template <class T>
    void reset(T* data)
    { Data* old = _data; _data = (Data*)data; delete old; }
};

template <class T>       std2::unique_ptr<T>& move(      std2::unique_ptr<T>& data) { return data; }
template <class T> const std2::unique_ptr<T>& move(const std2::unique_ptr<T>& data) { return data; }

template<class Data>
inline unique_ptr<Data> make_unique() { return unique_ptr<Data>(new Data()); }
```

Classes:

```
struct A {
    A() { std::cout << "A()" << std::endl; }
    virtual ~A() { std::cout << "~A()" << std::endl; };
};

struct B : public A {
    B() : A() { std::cout << "B()" << std::endl; }
    ~B() { std::cout << "~B" << std::endl; };
};
```

Output for the first option. Looks like some additional copying (memcpy) has been done.

> ```
> A()
> B()
> 0: cons
> 1: copy cons const <T>
> 0: deleting :0000000000000000
> 2: copy cons <T>
> Inside pass_through
> 3: copy cons <T>
> 2: deleting :0000000000000000
> 3: deleting :000001CC492B1790   // This one is #3
> ~B
> ~A()
> 3: deleting :000001CC492B1790   // This one is also #3
> ```

Could you help me with this double deleting?

Comment: afaik `unique_ptr` is impossible to implement in C++98 because C++98 didn't have move semantics.

Comment: and you forgot to ask a question.

Comment: It's not possible to fully implement a drop-in replacement for `std::unique_ptr` in C++98.  You will always need at least explicit move calls in your return statements.  If you want an example, look at [`boost::movelib::unique_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/move/reference.html#header.boost.move.unique_ptr_hpp), but definitely read their section on [move emulation limitations](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_73_0/doc/html/move/emulation_limitations.html).

Comment: @bolov asked a question. I don't need real `unique_ptr`. I'm going to write all code with C++11 conformant compilers, but I need this code to run with C++03 compiler.

Comment: you might as well write this a C++23 compiler. It doesn't matter. It won't work in pre C++11 because before C++11 C++ didn't have move semantics. For c++03 the best you can do is [`std::auto_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) which already exists you don't need to reinvent an (already troublesome) wheel.

Comment: @bolov maybe you can explain from where this additional copying is coming?

Comment: @yola I don't see anything obvious at first glance. You should debug your program.

Comment: @bolov this is an interesting case. The error goes away if outer `std2::move` is removed. A temporary forms I believe. But why it forms in some cases and not in anothers this is the question.

Comment: And the answer is: debug the program

Comment: One of the main reason of C++ 11 move semantic is exactly because it was hard to make such classes that properly works in all situations. That was a well known problem at that time.

Comment: Also, how could you expect your code to work correctly when you don't even write copy constructor and assignment operator? This is basic C++ knowledge that compiler generated copy constructor would be prefered to template one. Same for assignment. Thus your are missing at least 4 functions when taking into account the constness of parameters.

Comment: @Phil1970 there are both. Look into *unique_ptr implementation* section.

Comment: @Yola You must read **C++ Gotchas — Avoiding Common Problems in Coding and Design** by **Stephen C. Dewhurst** (Addison-Wesley). **Gotcha #88: Misunderstanding Templated Copy Operations.** This item explain exactly your problem in a book published in 2002. Anyway, given that the standard implementation has them, you should not have removed them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are never copy constructors.

```
unique_ptr(const unique_ptr<Data>& other)
unique_ptr(unique_ptr<Data>& other)
```

write these two.

Also similar for `operator=`.

Comment: Argh, I had tried it, you can see *<T>* in my logging, this is because I had had non-templated version as well, but removed it because it was never called, at least I thought so. But now it works. Thank you very much.